# When a creature's proficiency bonus is doubled for a skill, is it marked as such in its statblock?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, skills, proficiency

I'm very new to the books of D&D 5e.

I see in the introduction of the MM that they specify the proficiency bonus for CR, and that [at times it will be doubled to account for the creature's "heightened expertise"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/monsters#Skills), but when I visit the tables for the creatures, I don't see something that identifies that outright.

Is there something like an asterisk, footnote, or something that I could be looking for to identify when a creature's proficiency bonus is doubled in its statblock?

When I'm speed reading I'm just getting thrown off if I try to do the math in my head.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: While that is tangentially related, it's definitely not a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's nothing. Monsters aren't bound by the normal math and "double proficiency" is just a common way to increase the number by a predictable amount without making it too dangerous/powerful.

You can check the Goblin as an example; it has heightened proficiency on Stealth, but you can't see it anywhere unless you do the math.

It shouldn't really matter, either way. All monsters stats are designed so as a DM, you can use them directly; you never have to make any modifications or calculations. Just read the number in the block and apply it.

(You might have to make some changes to stats if you are a player using Shapechange, Wildshape, or an ability like that)

Comment: would be nice if it was at Least in a index of listing creatures for what they are good at.  Having a list of things exceptional at stealth or etc would make finding interesting monsters easier

Comment: @Deceptecium: For that you should just be comparing modifiers, without regard whether they come from to double proficiency or just good stats. Alas, none of the monster lists on the various websites let you search by skill modifier, as far as I can tell. So you're right that it would be a useful thing to have.

Comment: True you could just look at modifiers, but sometimes its funny to find and throw something at party with good stealth they didn't expect. Kinda like dragons with their +6 or higher stealth bonus. Do small little Pete dragon esq session